# Cant access wamp from Local network

Tags: php, configuration

I installed on VM--->server 2019, and on the server  i have configured a Wamp server 3.1.9 version php 7.1,  I have access to my project on my server, also i changed my localhost project to domain name and again i access to my project(url with authentication with no problem) its a ticketing system my project

**The real problem now is that i can't connect from another pc on my local network from another vm machine
both the server and the client are on the same  VMnet(0)**

this is my conf [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVXLi.png)

Comment: What is your ipconfig command result ?! it's Linux or Windows OS?

Comment: Both Windows OS, windows server 2019 with wamp and the client windows 10 enterprise edition,, the ipconfig both they have ip from my domain 192.168.1.1 the server and the client has 192.168.1.100 from dhcp service!!

Comment: Both the server and client have 192.168.1.1 dns, expect server has one more dns ::1                   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . :   ::1
                                 192.168.1.1

Comment: Did you share the network from VM to main Windows? 
Anyway just goto C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts 
in VM and put the IP for your main  windows inside it 

IP.XX.XX.XXX wampwebsite.test

Also, there is another solution you can share folder [ wamp / htdocs  ] with Main Windows and open it in IDE to make changes then the changes will be run on VM Windows

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!!
Adding httpd.exe(WAMP Apache) application to firewall, rule application open connections for port 80, And one more rule for MySQL database tcp rule open connections for port 3306!!